# Spring Reactive: java.io.IOException: Connection closed prematurely, when trying to unit test a service returning flux

Tags: java, spring, reactive-programming, spring-webflux

Working with spring reactive application, I created a rest service which produces an event every second. The code for my rest controller is:

```
@GetMapping(value = "/events", produces = MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM_VALUE)
public Flux<Event> getEvents() {
    Flux<Event> eventFlux = Flux.fromStream(Stream.generate(() -> new Event(new Random().nextLong(), "Hello Event")));
    Flux<Long> emmitFlux = Flux.interval(Duration.ofSeconds(1));
    return Flux.zip(eventFlux, emmitFlux).map(Tuple2::getT1);
}
```

And the method to unit test this looks like:

```
webTestClient.get()
    .uri("/events")
    .accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus()
    .isOk();

FluxExchangeResult<Event> result = webTestClient.get().uri("/events").accept(MediaType.TEXT_EVENT_STREAM)
    .exchange()
    .expectStatus()
    .isOk()
    .returnResult(Event.class);

Flux<Event> eventFlux = result.getResponseBody();

StepVerifier.create(eventFlux)        
    .expectSubscription()
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .expectNextCount(0)
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .expectNextCount(1)
    .thenAwait(Duration.ofSeconds(1))
    .expectNextCount(2);
```

But when I run the test, I get this error:

```
java.io.IOException: Connection closed prematurely
```

Have anyone faced and resolved any similar issue with spring-reactive?

Comment: You are missing @ResponseBody in controller method.

Comment: I am using @RestController so I am not required to add @ ResponseBody to the methods.

Answer (score 0):

You must always end a `StepVerifier` chain with a `.verify();`, otherwise it won't subscribe to it and nothing will happen.

In this case, because it's an infinite stream, you must also have a `thenCancel()` right before the verify, otherwise your test could run indefinitely.